# no items returned in a view with a filter on a calculated column

Tags: 2010, filter, calculated-column, view

I'm having a strange issue and Google isn't helping me much in figuring out why.

I have a custom list with 3 fields:

1. Title
2. Year

   - calculated column
   - `=left([title], 4)`
   - single line of text
3. Month

   - calculated column
   - `=MID([Title],6,2)+0`
   - single line of text

I create 3 items and end up with a list like so:

```
| Title                 | Year  | Month     |
|---------------------- |------ |-------    |
| 2016-02-17T18:00:00Z  | 2016  | 2         |
| 2016-02-10T18:00:00Z  | 2016  | 2         |
| 2015-03-03T18:00:00Z  | 2015  | 3         |
```

So far so good.

I can create a view and filter on `Year` `is equal to` `2` and that works as expected.

But if I create a view and filter on `Month` `is equal to` `2` then the view shows no items.

I cannot figure out what gives?